# Why my laptop sleeps automatically

Tags: ubuntu, sleep, shutdown

I leave my laptop running a python program (with infinite loop) with the lid closed. The laptop is running Ubuntu OS. I have changed the *what closing lid will do* option to "do nothing" for both on battery and while charging. But still after a day or so it shuts down/sleeps automatically. What else do I need to do to prevent this?

Comment: The right place for this question is http://superuser.com/ .

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion!